# Xamarin Essentials Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged event is called twice

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have tested both on iOS simulator and android emulator and found that **"Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged" event triggers twice at a time**.
Whenever I changed the connectivity on virtual devices(emulator and simulator), the two times triggering issue replicates which deals in calling my function twice.

I've also gone through this:
https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1068 but found no solution.
I am using the latest version of Xamarin Essentials till todays date i.e. 1.7.3.
Is there any possible way to control this event?

Comment: Design your function so that calling it twice is harmless. To do so, keep track of the access state (e.NetworkAccess, and any other properties of `ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e` param that you care about) that you saw most recently. Then when your function is called again, if it is the same information, do nothing.

Comment: Hi ToolmakerSteve,
Previously, I tried by putting a flag, it didn't work. And again by string values but it didn't work. It always ended up by initial value and was really hard to control the event.Therefore, I was compelled to post the question.
But now, yeah by storing the value in Xamarin Preferences worked really well and the problem has been solved.
Thank you so much for help! :)